# Can I make decode(errors="ignore") the default for all strings in a Python 2.7 program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decode

I have a Python 2.7 program that writes out data from various external applications. I continually get bitten by exceptions when I write to a file until I add `.decode(errors="ignore")` to the string being written out. (FWIW, opening the file as `mode="wb"` doesn't fix this.)

Is there a way to say "ignore encoding errors on all strings in this scope"?

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 20):

You cannot redefine methods on built-in types, and you cannot change the default value of the `errors` parameter to `str.decode()`.  There are other ways to achieve the desired behaviour, though.

**The slightly nicer way:** Define your own `decode()` function:

```
def decode(s, encoding="ascii", errors="ignore"):
    return s.decode(encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
```

Now, you will need to call `decode(s)` instead of `s.decode()`, but that's not too bad, isn't it?

**The hack:** You can't change the default value of the `errors` parameter, but you *can* overwrite what the handler for the default `errors="strict"` does:

```
import codecs
def strict_handler(exception):
    return u"", exception.end
codecs.register_error("strict", strict_handler)
```

This will essentially change the behaviour of `errors="strict"` to the standard `"ignore"` behaviour.  Note that this will be a global change, affecting all modules you import.

I recommend neither of these two ways.  The real solution is to get your encodings right.  (I'm well aware that this isn't always possible.)

Answer (score 6):

[As mentioned in my thread on the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662847/tracking-down-implicit-unicode-conversions-in-python-2) the hack from *[Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach)* is even possible without a new function:

```
import codecs
codecs.register_error("strict", codecs.ignore_errors)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your setup is exactly, but you can derive a class from `str` and override its decode method:

```
class easystr(str):
    def decode(self):
        return str.decode(self, errors="ignore")
```

If you then convert all incoming strings to `easystr`, errors will be silently ignored:

```
line = easystr(input.readline())
```

That said, *decoding* a string converts it to unicode, which should never be lossy. Could you figure out which encoding your strings are using and give that as the `encoding` argument to `decode`? That would be a better solution (and you can still make it the default in the above way).

Yet another thing you should try is to *read* your data differently. Do it like this and the decoding errors may well disappear:

```
import codecs
input = codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding="latin-1") # or whatever
```